# Automatically set hight of ImageView and Button

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to set height of an image view and a Button to be automatically resized for different devices . I want to show the button below the imageview whatever the height of the image is.

I am trying this code :

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_btn"
        android:layout_bellow="imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it should fit the screen or scrolling is fine

Comment: it should fit the screen

Comment: below answer will work add scale type to center crop if image is bigger it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you are using LinerLayout, with android:orientantion="vertical". 
I'd use a layout_weight attribute, as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send_btn"
    android:layout_bellow="imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

It will automatically fill all the upper part with the image view.

By using layout_weight="1" and layout_height="wrap_content" in ImageView, you tell Android that ImageView is "important" and must fill in all the remaining space.

Comment: its work nicely but the resolution is changed , how can i fix that ?

Comment: You might want to add this to imageview: android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: i was trying to set  imageview: android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:scaleType="fitXY" but when i set the picture in image view the resolution changed